# VB6 .NET Interop - Performance issue

Tags: .net, vb6, com-interop

I'm trying to use a VB6 app consumed in a C# app. The VB6 App is a Winform app. To do this, I have modified the VB6 App (EXE) to a DLL. Then I've referenced it in my C# app. In my VB App, I've add a new Class with some methods just to open VB forms.

Everything works fine... except that if the form has many controls (30), the window is extremely slow to open (> 4s whereas < 1s in VB)

1/ Is this method good ?

2/ How to resolve this ?

Regards,

Florian

EDIT : I know where is the problem but I don't know how to resolve it. The method which is very slow to execute contains a dozen of sql string concatened by a ";" and the method
ex : sqlString = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;SELECT * FROM PUBLISHERS..."
OpenResultSet(strSelect) is called... a combobox is filled for each sql string

Comment: How is the form initialized? Are you passing lots of data from C# to VB6?

Comment: No, I don't pass any code from C# to vb6. In C# I just call this method : myVBApp.OpenFrmCustomer();

Answer (score 0):

From what you have written I would look at exactly how many rows / columns your 'SELECT * FROM XXXX' queries are returning.

SELECT * is generally considered bad practise as it can have massive performance implications (and will slow down for every column added to the table in the future, even if you don't need any data in that column) and if you have no WHERE clause your query will get slower every day that data is added to your table.