# .NET database calls slow when using COM Interop, fast via VB6

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb6, sql-server-2000, com-interop

After searching couple of days ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3802394/375460) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3822099/375460)), I believe I've found the problem and it seems identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3470039/375460). However, I have captured two execution plans to compare it but, they seem to be identical except execution time. (The Database server is SQL SERVER 2000)

***The Query executed in VB6 :***

EventClass : SQL:BatchCompleted

- CPU : 31
- Reads : 419
- Writes : 0
- Duration : **390**

EventClass : Audit Logout (I don't know if it's useful)

- CPU : 47
- Reads : 1295
- Writes : 0
- Duration : **920**

***The Query executed with .NET (Interop / COM VB6) :***

EventClass : SQL:BatchCompleted

- CPU : 16
- Reads : 419
- Writes : 0
- Duration : **1906**

EventClass : Audit Logout (I don't know if it's useful)

- CPU : 31
- Reads : 1295
- Writes : 0
- Duration : **4813**

Now the execution plan captured with the query with VB6 AND .NET (File comparison with UltraEdit) between SQL:BatchStarting and SQL:BatchCompleted EventClass :

```
Table Scan(OBJECT:([Resgu].[dbo].[stsIns] AS [si]), WHERE:([si].[IdEqIns]=NULL AND [si].[StsstsIns]>=0))

Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([Resgu].[dbo].[Uge].[pkUge] AS [u]), WHERE:([u].[StsUge]>=Convert([@1])))

Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([Resgu].[dbo].[Btt].[pkBtt] AS [b]), WHERE:([b].[StsBtt]>=Convert([@1])))

Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1001]=Convert([p].[IdEmp])+' - '+[p].[EmpName]+' - '+[p].[PreEmpName]))
  |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([Resgu].[dbo].[Employee].[pkEmployee] AS [p]), WHERE:([p].[StsEmployee]>=0))

Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1002]=Convert([t].[IdStruct])+' - '+[t].[LblTurn]+' - '+[s].[LblStruct]))
  |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([s].[IdStruct]))
       |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([Resgu].[dbo].[Struct].[pkStruct] AS [s]), WHERE:([s].[StsStruct]>=0))
       |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([Resgu].[dbo].[Turn].[pkTurn] AS [t]), SEEK:([t].[IdStruct]=[s].[IdStruct]),  WHERE:([t].[StsTurn]>=0) ORDERED FORWARD)

Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1002]=Convert([t].[IdStruct])+' - '+[t].[LblTurn]+' - '+[s].[LblStruct]))
  |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([s].[IdStruct]))
       |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([Resgu].[dbo].[Struct].[pkStruct] AS [s]), WHERE:([s].[StsStruct]>=0))
       |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([Resgu].[dbo].[Turn].[pkTurn] AS [t]), SEEK:([t].[IdStruct]=[s].[IdStruct]),  WHERE:([t].[StsTurn]>=0) ORDERED FORWARD)

Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1001]=Convert([s].[IdSite])+' - '+[s].[LblSite]))
  |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([Resgu].[dbo].[Site].[pkSite] AS [s]), WHERE:([s].[StsSite]>=0))

Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([Resgu].[dbo].[MarketType].[pkMarketType] AS [tm]), WHERE:([tm].[StsMarketType]>=Convert([@1])))

Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([Resgu].[dbo].[Flow].[pkFlow] AS [f]), WHERE:([f].[CatFlow]<Convert([@2]) AND [f].[StsFlow]>=Convert([@1])))

Table Scan(OBJECT:([Resgu].[dbo].[TypeInst] AS [ti]), WHERE:([ti].[StsTypeInst]>=Convert([@1])))

Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([Resgu].[dbo].[WeaSation].[pkWeaSation] AS [sm]), WHERE:([sm].[StsWeaSation]>=Convert([@1])))
```

I'm not an expert in Sql Profiling so I miss to check something but what ?

Regards,

Florian

Comment: can you post what query is being ran?

Comment: did this get resolved?  Did either answer help at all?

Comment: No it's not resolved but i think it's not about SQL Server itself. I would to close the topic but i have not the right to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of caching and parameter sniffing. I had some weird performance problems with some stored procedures and was able to narrow it down to some bad optimizations. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/khen1234/archive/2005/06/02/424228.aspx

Comment: If I test my query with SQL 2005 Server, I won't have no longer see this problem ?

Comment: I test the query with SQL Server 2008 but I have the same result.

Comment: it didn't directly answer the question, but I hate to see the bounty go to waste, and since I can't split the bounty, here you go.

Comment: I have seen this problem before. It was slow in vb but fast via EM. It was parameter sniffing, not sure if the environment gave clues about how to process the request. Also, it is my understanding the com interop may be slow compared to a native solution since the data has to be marshalled.

Answer (score 0):

Identical execution plans but different timings. Are the [connection settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259205%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) for both connections identical? Any difference in server load?

Comment: Regarding, the server load, there is no difference. It's the same server and queries are tested more times and each time I have the same result.

Comment: Regarding the Connection settings, Normally there is no difference too. But, I read that an .NET application accessing data with ADO (or RDO ?) is slower than ADO.NET...